# html toggle 2 background images

Tags: html, image, toggle

How can I toggle a background image between 2 different .gifs.

At the moment I have:

```
<td style='background:url(image1.gif)'>
```

But would like it to toggle between image1.gif and image2.gif every 1 second.

Would it need some javascript or css or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it - http://jsfiddle.net/Jc2Bq/

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="bgimage">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS (replace the colors with the images you want)

```
td.bgimage{
     padding: 10px;
     background: #333;
}

td.bgimage.toggled{
     background: #f00;
}
```

Javascript

```
function colorChange(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('td.bgimage').toggleClass('toggled');
        colorChange();
    }, 1000);
}

colorChange();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use JavaScript using the `setTimeout()` function ([reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)).

Answer (score 0):

Without JavaScript you can do something using CSS like:

```
​td:hover {
 background: url(image2.gif) !important;   
}​
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4DKNq/1/)** using colors instead of images.

Example 2 (targets a class):

```
​td.someclass:hover {
 background: url(image2.gif) !important;   
}​
```

Comment: could I set it to a class instead of the 'td'?

Answer (score 0):

**Css**

```
.bg_one{background:url(image1.gif)}
.bg_two{background:url(image2.gif)}
```

**Html**

```
<td class='bg1'></td>
```

**Javascript(jquery)**

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($('td').hasClass('bg_one'))
       $('td').toggleClass('bg_two');
    else
       $('td').toggleClass('bg_one');  
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain way of doing it without jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>  
  <title>Sample</title>

  <style type="text/css" id="vbulletin_css">
    #cell {      
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: url('image1.gif');
    }
  </style>


  <script type="text/javascript">

  // start by setting current background image flag
  var currentImage = 1;

  function init() {
    // start calling function 'changeImage' every second
    setInterval(changeImage,1000);    
  }

  function changeImage() {
    if (currentImage == 1) {
      // set background image to image2      
      document.getElementById('cell').style.background = "url('image2.gif')";
      currentImage = 2;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('cell').style.background = "url('image1.gif')";
      currentImage = 1;
    }
  }

  window.onload = init;  

  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="cell"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```